# Add Parameter in a query in MS SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am working with Visual Basic and MS SQL, and I would like to know how to do add a parameter in my query. In general I read a table from my DB and I copy some field in another VB class:

```
Dim data = From e In table
           Where e.param >= param
           Select New VBClass With {
               .field1 = e.field1
               .field2 = e.field2
           }
```

The problem is that I would like to add a parameter to the query if for instance a string is not empty, the query become:

```
Dim data = From e In table
           Where e.param >= param And e.StrParam = StrInput
           Select New VBClass With {
               .field1 = e.field1
               .field2 = e.field2
           }
```

otherwise the query remain the same.

Comment: Why the MySQL if you're working with MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand, but I can tell you that a similar code is working with a MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this with a simple `If` statement:

```vb
Dim data as IEnumerable(Of VBClass)

If string.IsNullOrEmpty(StrInput) Then
    data = From e In table
           Where e.param >= param And e.StrParam = StrInput
           Select New VBClass With {
               .field1 = e.field1
               .field2 = e.field2
           }
Else
    data = From e In table
           Where e.param >= param And e.StrParam = StrInput
           Select New VBClass With {
               .field1 = e.field1
               .field2 = e.field2
           }
End If
```

If you've **lots** of independent values, then you can do:

```vb
Dim query = table.Where(Function (e) e.param >= param)

If Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(StrInput) Then
    query = query.Where(Function (e) e.StrParam = StrInput)
End If

' Repeat for each property

Dim data = From e In query
           Select New VBClass With {
               .field1 = e.field1
               .field2 = e.field2
           }
```

The query won't be executed until you enumerate it, so this is quite efficient (well, as it can be checking so many columns individually)

Comment: The problem is that my class has 80 properties, so I was searching for a different solution